# Taking data from a JSON array and outputting it through a function

Tags: javascript, json

All I want to do is get this information from JSON into a console.log in my main JavaScript file. This is a practice exercise for a class I am taking and I want to make a good grade tomorrow. Please help me?

I have tried this:

```
//JSON function attempt
var jsonDataPull = function(jsonATMData) {
    for (var key in jsonATMData.ATMData) {
        for (var otherKey in jsonATMData.ATMData[key]) {
            console.log(jsonDataPull.jsonATMData[key][otherKey]);
        }
    }
};


// actual JSON data I formatted to be able to bring back into my function. 
var jsonATMData = {
    "ATMData": [
        {
            "atmLocation": "Main Street",    
            "atmSumMoney": 3500,
            "timeToSteal": 3
        },
        {    
            "atmLocation": "14th Street",
            "atmSumMoney": 2200,
            "timeToSteal": 3
        },    
        {
            "atmLocation": "Peachtree Street",
            "atmSumMoney": 1700,
            "timeToSteal": 4
        },
        {
            "atmLocation": "Peachtree Street",
            "atmSumMoney": 300,
            "timeToSteal": 1
        },
        {
            "atmLocation": "Monroe Drive",
            "atmSumMoney": 660,
            "timeToSteal": 1
        },
        {
            "atmLocation": "Ponce",
            "atmSumMoney": 5500,
            "timeToSteal": 7
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON. You have a JS object, containing one property which is an array, which contains several other objects. All noted in JS literal syntax. JSON is a string which can be parsed by many platforms into native data structures.

Comment: That is helpful. My supposed JSON data is not even formatted as such? I guess I need to go back to the drawing board on my JSON.

Comment: @jaalude, I also wanted to let you know that the JSON data I am supposed to be including isn't having to be called via ajax because everything is to be stored locally. We are not parsing data from a remote source or anything like that.

Comment: @PHPglue ish. The thing is, I am simply outputting to the console via Firebug to tell a story. I know it's really trivial and quite elementary in nature, but this class is focused on getting my brain to think in terms of code.

Comment: Take a look at this to see how JSON is actually a string, and gets parsed into the data structure you originally posted: http://jsfiddle.net/2zEhR/1/

Comment: @JAAulde nicely done sir! That was a tremendous help for me because I now see it formatted properly in terms of how I need to use it! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

JSONAtmData.ATMData is basically an array of objects (picture it like [object, object, object...]), so you can just do this

```
for ( var i = 0; i < jsonATMData.ATMData.length; i++ ) {
    console.log(jsonATMData.ATMData[i].atmLocation);
    console.log(jsonATMData.ATMData[i].atmSumMoney);
    console.log(jsonATMData.ATMData[i].timeToSteal);
}
```

Comment: I seriously appreciate you. So, if I wanted to pick one piece of information out of each object, I would drop [i] and replace with the corresponding index number?

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe:

```
for(var i in jsonATMData){
  for(var n in jsonATMData[i]){
    for(var c in jsonATMData[i][n]){
      console.log('PROPERTY:'+c+'; VALUE:'+jsonATMData[i][n][c]);
    }
  }
}
```

This should be able to show multiple Arrays within your `jsonATMData`.

Comment: @PHPglue that is pretty much true. When I try to use this in my code, it does not turn out correctly. Thank you for pitching in though, I didn't expect all these awesome responses from people.